# How can I subplot multiple network graphs using plotly for r?

Tags: r, graphics, plotly

I would like to have one image with all my network graphics and I tried using the `subplot` function in plotly, but it messes up the graphics. Below is a general example so you can see what I mean:

```
library(plotly)
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)

data(karate)
G <- upgrade_graph(karate)
L <- layout.circle(G)
vs <- V(G)
es <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(G))

Nv <- length(vs)
Ne <- length(es[1]$V1)
Xn <- L[,1]
Yn <- L[,2]

network <- plot_ly(x = ~Xn, y = ~Yn, mode = "markers", text = vs$label, 
hoverinfo = "text")
edge_shapes <- list()
for(i in 1:Ne) {
  v0 <- es[i,]$V1
  v1 <- es[i,]$V2

  edge_shape = list(
    type = "line",
    line = list(color = "#030303", width = 0.3),
    x0 = Xn[v0],
    y0 = Yn[v0],
    x1 = Xn[v1],
    y1 = Yn[v1]
  )

  edge_shapes[[i]] <- edge_shape
}
axis <- list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline 
= FALSE)

p <- layout(
  network,
  title = 'Karate Network',
  shapes = edge_shapes,
  xaxis = axis,
  yaxis = axis
)

p2 <- layout(
  network,
  title = 'Karate Network',
  shapes = edge_shapes,
  xaxis = axis,
  yaxis = axis
)

p3 <- layout(
  network,
  title = 'Karate Network',
  shapes = edge_shapes,
  xaxis = axis,
  yaxis = axis
)

subplot(p, p2, p3)
```

It ends up looking like this:

[image: Teste]

Does anyone how can I fix this? Or if the `subplot` function really doesn't work with network graphics what can I use to merge this type of graphic together? Thanks!